# My date conversion from textbox is working in localhost but not in online server in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

my code for converting date is given below,

```
        DateTime dat1 = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDOB.Text);
        string date2 = dat1.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

i got error like this,

Exception Details: System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Source Error:

Line 68:             DateTime dat1 = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDOB.Text);

how can recover this,plzzzz help...

Comment: can u tell wht comes in txtDOB.text?

Comment: 20-03-2014 ie dd-MM-yyyy format using ajaxtoolkit calendar extender, can you help me?

Comment: write logic to format your ui format to MM/dd/yyyy using string manipulation before converting

Comment: thankyou but the date format to show in text box is dd-MM-yyyy. When I used this format the problem arised

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you should  Use DateTime.ParseExact with the format "MM/dd/yyyy"

```
DateTime.ParseExact(txtDOB.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                        .ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

you can go though the below link for more information

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx

Comment: Thankyou, but it also not working, showing error as System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Source Error: 



Line 74:             DateTime dtObject = DateTime.ParseExact(txtDOB.Text,
Line 75:                                             "MM/dd/yyyy",
Line 76:                                             CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Comment: glad it worked. Make it as an answer if you think it helped! @user3122272